# Category taxonomy template not working for custom post

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post type using following code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_team_post_type' );
function create_team_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
      ),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    )
  );
}
```

and taxonomy using following code:

```
function taxonomies_portfolio() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Portfolio categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Portfolio categories', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Query portfolio categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All portfolio categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit portfolio category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update portfolio category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add Edit portfolio category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New portfolio category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_category', 'portfolio', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'taxonomies_portfolio', 0 );
```

When I click on category that is navigating to `index.php`. I created a file name called `taxnomy-portfolio_category.php`. The URL is showing `url/taxnomy-portfolio_category.php/cat_name` but the result is `index.php`.

Comment: Really, `taxnomy`?

Comment: yes.I need template how to display categories.

Comment: Try the correct name with `taxonomy`.

Comment: taxonomy in there but not redirecting.Can youu help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hierarchy for a custom taxonomy is listed below:

`taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php`: For example, if the taxonomy is named “sometax,” and the taxonomy’s term is “someterm,” WordPress would look for a file named taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php.

`taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`: For example, if the taxonomy is named “sometax,” WordPress would look for a file named taxonomy-sometax.php

```
taxonomy.php

archive.php

index.php
```

url:

```
/you_site.com/portfolio_category/term_name
```

Provided that the settings Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks found:

```
/%category%/%postname%.html
```